# Expanding an std::tuple

Tags: c++11, tuples

Let's say I have a C++0x tuple:

```
tuple<int,int,int> t(1,2,3);
```

Now I can do the following to extract the elements of t:

```
int i,j,k;
make_tuple<int&,int&,int&>(i,j,k) = t;
```

Is there any less verbose way of achieving this? I know about the `get<0>(t)` syntax; it is not what I am after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `tie` for that:

```
std::tie(i, j, k) = t;
```

Comment: Excellent, I knew I had seen it was possible.